# Placeholders resolution for client specific configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am learning about [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) project capabilities. I wondered whether it is possible to use a placeholders for application specific configuration?

For example:

My application.yml file:

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:/config
```

The config folder contains a my-app.yml file:

```
key:
  value: ${my.password}
```

The server started with -Dmy.password=password environment variable. A get request to /my-app/native url returns:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "profiles": ["native"],
    "label": null,
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [{
        "name": "classpath:/config/my-app.yml",
        "source": {
            "key.value": "${my.password}"
        }
    }]
}
```

The env property in placeholder returned to the client without evaluation, there is a way to evaluate the property before sending the response to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `override` feature to set `key.value`'s value when starting your server:

```
-Dspring.cloud.config.server.overrides.key.value=overrideValue
```

I *think* your clients must be started afterwards.

## [Spring documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_property_overrides):

> #### Property Overrides
>
> The Config Server has an “overrides” feature that lets the operator provide configuration properties to all applications. The overridden properties cannot be accidentally changed by the application with the normal Spring Boot hooks. To declare overrides, add a map of name-value pairs to `spring.cloud.config.server.overrides`, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> spring:   
>   cloud:
>     config:
>       server:
>         overrides:
>           foo: bar
> ```
>
> The preceding examples causes all applications that are config clients to read `foo=bar`, independent of their own configuration.
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is solves partially my issue. For example, in case the configuration server provides different values (same key) for different applications. One value is taken from an environment while the other hard coded in configuration file. Any option to control it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible (at least not that I know of). do your passwords change often ? Why don't you use the spring boot cloud {cipher} in your server GIT. You'd have one {cipher} per client (organized by applicationName or different labels) ? You'd have the benefits of having encrypted passwords. Would that fit your needs ?  If you don't know about cyper, let me know, I'll update the answer

Comment: I do familiar with the cipher functionality. The problem is that password may changed during installation and upon request.

Comment: Then, I don't know what else can be done (not saying there isn't something, just that I'm not aware of it).